# Sequelize belongsTo change identifier

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make mysql query with sequelize ORM to select user name on friends.user_id.

so far I came up with this solution, it works kind of good but it selects `AS Users ON Friends.friend_id` instead of `AS Users ON Friends.user_id`

and the relations is being described here

```
db.Friends.belongsTo(db.Users, { as: 'UserOpUsers', sourceKey: 'friend_id', foreignKey: 'user_id' })
```

the query does

```
SELECT `Friends`.`id` AS `friend_id`, `Users`.`username`, `Users`.`id`, `Friends`.`status` FROM `wd_friends_relations` AS `Friends` LEFT OUTER JOIN `info_users` AS `Users` ON `Friends`.`friend_id` = `Users`.`id` WHERE `Friends`.`friend_id` = 2;
```

but it should make

```
SELECT `Friends`.`id` AS `friend_id`, `Users`.`username`, `Users`.`id`, `Friends`.`status` FROM `wd_friends_relations` AS `Friends` LEFT OUTER JOIN `info_users` AS `Users` ON `Friends`.`user_id` = `Users`.`id` WHERE `Friends`.`friend_id` = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no sourceKey in belongsTo Association http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-belongsTo, It is only present in HasOne and HasMany relations. So use something like this,

```
db.Friends.belongsTo(db.Users, { as: 'UserOpUsers', foreignKey: 'user_id' })
```

It will create the query like this,

```
SELECT `Friends`.`id` AS `friend_id`, `Users`.`username`, `Users`.`id`, `Friends`.`status` FROM `wd_friends_relations` AS `Friends` LEFT OUTER JOIN `info_users` AS `Users` ON `Friends`.`user_id` = `Users`.`id` WHERE `Friends`.`friend_id` = 2;
```